# I can't get my angular 6 *ngIf statement to work

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I can't seem to get the *ngIf statement to work.  Am I missing something? 
I've included the *ngIf statement in a div and then added a

tag to display the message should there not be any posts/bookings.  please help :)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h4>Bookings</h4>
    </div>
    <span class="col-6">
      <button 
      class="btn btn-primary float-right btn-sm" 
      routerLinkActive="active" 
      routerLink="/createBooking">
        New Booking</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row" *ngIf="bookings.length > 0">
    <div class="col-12">
      <a
      href="#"
      class="list-group-item clearfix"
      *ngFor="let booking of bookings">
        <div class="float-left">
          <p class="list-group-item-text"
            >{{ booking.bookingDate }}
              <br>
              {{ booking.clientName }}
              <br>
              {{ booking.projectTitle }}
              <br>
              ${{ booking.rate }}
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <p *ngIf="bookings.length <= 0">No bookings added yet!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Post your ts file, what does `bookings` look like? How does that get data.. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `*ngIf` that looks like this:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="bookings.length > 0">
```

Inside of this `div`, you have a nested `*ngIf` that looks like this:

```
<p *ngIf="bookings.length <= 0">No bookings added yet!</p>
```

Now, imagine the following simplified version of what you have:

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="bookings.length > 0">
    <p *ngIf="bookings.length <= 0">No bookings added yet!</p>
</div>
```

When you look at this, it's clear that when `bookings.length` is not `> 0`, the top-level `div` will not be rendered. If the top-level `div` isn't rendered, it's child `p` cannot possibly be rendered as it's *inside* of a `div` that isn't being rendered: `bookings.length` cannot be *both > 0 **and** <= 0*, so the `p` element is never rendered.